# How to add "Select" clause to an EF4.1 query in MVC3 app

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have a simple entity framework query in an MVC3 app, like so

```
var instances= db.Instances.Include(c => c.CompanyLead).Include(c => c.SalesLead).Include(c => c.Customer);

        return View(instances);
```

This query works fine and essentially returns all instances.  However, I need to filter this query and basically add the phrase:

var instances= db.Instances.Include(c => c.CompanyLead).Include(c => c.SalesLead).Include(c => c.Customer)**WHERE InstanceType = x**

I don't want to revert to an ObjectQuery class with a DB Context object.  I thought I would be able to alter this query. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var instances = db.Instances.Where(c => c.InstanceType ==
>   "x").Include(c => c.CompanyLead).Include(c =>c.SalesLead).Include(c
>   =>c.Customer)